# "Connection timed out" on specific website but ping works

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, router, dns

I have a problem accessing www.mafiamofo.com website through any browser, I'm getting "connection timed out" in Firefox for example.

I have 2 IP addresses from the same ISP. One IP goes directly in one PC, where the website can be accessed fine. The second IP goes through a router into the second PC - where I can't access directly that website.

The odd thing is that both from the router and the 2nd PC I can ping the server, but the webpage won't load in browser. I've flushed DNS, reset the router, cleared cookies and history and nothing changed.

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved. It was the IPv4 SPI Firewall Protection enabled in the router, I disabled it and now I have no more problems. I don't know what that specific website is dealing with, but now it's all ok.